# Asp.Net Core - Need to access to HttpContext instance from instances generated without Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, service-locator

I'm using Asp.Net Core RC1, and I've to access to an `HttpContext` instance from instances generated by a model generator (from interceptors of `Castle.Core`, for be exact). Model generator has to be a single instance through the entire application.

I need to create an instance of `ModelGenerator` into startup file, because it is used into static lambdas needed to configure some serializers. Serializers are statically registered, so I have to write into startup:

```
var modelGenerator = new ModelGenerator();
Serializers.Configure(modelGenerator); // static use of model generator instance
```

I also add modelGenerator as singleton instance for other uses with DI.

```
services.AddInstance<IModelGenerator>(modelGenerator);
```

What I would have done with DI is to take a `IHttpContextAccessor` interface from ModelGenerator's constructor, but into this context I can't because I don't have an instance on startup. I need something like a ServiceLocator to call from ModelGenerator, or some other patter that I ignore.

How can reach an updated HttpContext instance, with information of current request, from interceptors generated by ModelGenerator?

Comment: "Serializers are statically registered" - why? The whole point of lifetime management in DI is to move away from static instances. If you don't use static instances and instead use singleton lifestyle, you don't have this issue.

Comment: I know, but it is not due to my code, and I can't change it.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that there is no way to get an instance of `HttpContext` in application startup. This makes sense - in previous versions of MVC this wasn't possible in IIS integrated mode or OWIN.

So what you have are 2 issues:

- How do you get the `IHttpContextAccessor` into your serializer?
- How do you ensure the `HttpContext` is not accessed until it is available?

The first issue is pretty straightforward. You just need to use constructor injection on `IHttpContextAccessor`.

```
public interface ISerializer
{
    void Test();
}

public class ModelGenerator : ISerializer
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public ModelGenerator(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var context = this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        // Use the context
    }
}
```

And to register...

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Other code...

    // Add the model generator
    services.AddTransient<ISerializer, ModelGenerator>();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var serializers = app.ApplicationServices.GetServices<ISerializer>();
    foreach (var serializer in serializers)
    {
        Serializers.Configure(serializer);
    }

    // Other code...
}
```

The second issue can be resolved by moving whatever initialization calls that you require `HttpContext` in into a global filter.

```
public class SerializerFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        // TODO: Put some kind of if condition (possibly a 
        // global static variable) here to ensure this 
        // only runs when needed.
        Serializers.Test();
    }
}
```

And to register the filter globally:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Other code...

    // Add the global filter for the serializer
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new SerializerFilter());
    });

    // Other code...
}
```

If your `Serializers.Configure()` method requires `HttpContext` to work, then you will need to move that call into the global filter.